# Nginx not passing args or even the headers to auth server

Tags: nginx, authentication

I have the following configuration on my NGINX server.

```
    location /login/  {
            auth_request /auth;
            auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
            proxy_ssl_verify              off;
            proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            proxy_ssl_certificate cert.pem;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate cert.crt;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
            proxy_pass https://www.myshop.com;
    }

    location /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass              http://myvalidator:8080/validator$is_args$args;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
```

Checking the validator side, the request is done but the URL query is not sent, nor even the original headers.
How can I send the original query or values from the original header to the validator server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `proxy_pass_request_body on;`
It Indicates whether the header fields of the original request are passed to the proxied server.

```
location /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass              http://myvalidator:8080/validator$is_args$args;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to do it, but the auth request is casted to a GET. 